# Double improper integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\iint_D \frac{(x+y) e^{y-x}}{x^{2}y^{2}}dx \, dy$$
where
$$D= \{(x,y)  ;   0\leq y+1\leq x ,   xy\geq 1 \}$$

I am not intressted in sovling this particular exemple but I want to understand the general approch of solving double improper integrals , I don't know alot about the theory and my book is not explaining it so well .

My main questions are :

1)How much of the rules of normal double integrals are still valid ? like changing the order ect .

2) is it true that if the inner integral converges / diverges so does the double integral ?

3) What difficulties accurs when the function is both negative and positive in the region I am integrating from ?

4) How to think in general about this , and can anyone recommend a good book or PDF that explains the theory in a simple way ? I just started in this topic and I have no intuition about it whatsoever.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**
Make the change of variable

$u=xy$

$v=x-y$

I belive everything will be simplified with the Jacobian.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), it will help you solve many of your questions. [This](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/20e-lecture16.pdf) document is also helpful

1. You can definitely change the integration order provided both integrals converge
2. Not necesarily. Take this example

   $$
    \int_{x = 0}^{\infty} dx\int_{y = -1}^1 dy\; \frac{e^{xy}}{x} =  \int_{x = 0}^{\infty} dx\; (e^{x} - e^{-x})
    $$

   which clearly diverges
3. It usually means trouble. Look at the last example of the Wiki's entry